# Pullback object in the category of modules

Tags: ring-theory, category-theory, modules

What is the construction of pull back object (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullback_(category_theory))    in the category of left $R$-modules  ?  i.e. let $X,Y,Z$ be left $R$-modules and $f:X\to Z ; g:Y\to Z$ be $R$-module homomorphisms , then how do we construct their pullback object ? I know how to construct the Pushout object, but I am unable to figure out what is the Pullback object . Please help . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The pullback will be a submodule of $X\oplus Y$; that of all $(x,y)\in X\oplus Y$ with $f(x)=g(y)$.

This is a special case of the general construction of pullbacks via
direct products and equalizers.

Comment: what are the pullback maps $p_1 : P \to X ; p_2 : P \to Y$ where $P$ is the Pullback ?

Comment: @misao just the restrictions of the projections from $X\oplus Y$.

Comment: This is also a special case of the fact that pullbacks, and limits in general, are calculated pointwise in categories of models of Lawvere theories, which is to say for most "algebraic" objects the underlying set of the limit is the limit of the underlying set, and we can equip it with operations in the obvious way.

Answer (score 2):

It is the subset of $X\times Y$ defined by $\{ (x,y):f(x)=g(y)\}$.